# how to display mulitple dictionary or array data in single tableview cell in swift ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to iOS development can any one give me some idea in swift. I have JSON data after parsing i am storing data in array like example.

```
"orderId" : 146,
"total" : 2,
"created_at" : "2016-09-19 11:08:51",
"categories" : [
               {
                  "name" : "Bleach",
                  "qrCode" : "SRY-001-0098",
                  "weight" : 1,
                  "categoryId" : "57dbd9ca8e1a0919c9075d13",
                  "amount" : 1
                },
                {
                  "name" : "Normal (26+ lbs)",
                  "qrCode" : "SRY-001-0099",
                  "weight" : 1,
                  "categoryId" : "57dbd9708e1a094ecb10cfb1",
                  "amount" : 1
                }
              ],
"completed_at" : "2016-09-19 00:00:00"
```

I have four arrays :

1. orderarray
2. totalarray
3. createatarrays
4. cartegoriesarray
5. completedarray

   orderarray[0] = 146

   totalarray[0] = 2

   createatarrays[0] = "2016-09-19 11:08:51"

   cartegoriesarray[0]  =

   ```
   [
           {
             "name" : "Bleach",
             "qrCode" : "SRY-001-0098",
             "weight" : 1,
             "categoryId" : "57dbd9ca8e1a0919c9075d13",
             "amount" : 1
           },
           {
             "name" : "Normal",
             "qrCode" : "SRY-001-0099",
             "weight" : 1,
             "categoryId" : "57dbd9708e1a094ecb10cfb1",
             "amount" : 1
           }
   ]
   ```

   completedarray[0] = "2016-09-19 00:00:00"

Using indexpathrow i can able to display orderarray, totalarray, createdarray based on index path in tableview cell.

But here categoryarray how can i display inside array again two dictionary is there ?

I want to display name" : "Bleach",  "name" : "Normal" in single tableview cell based on index path like categoryarray[0]

How to get these two names in single string plz give me some idea..

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the `catergoryarray` and get each dictionary out. Then you can get the individual values out of the dictionary.

```
var name = "";
//Loop the array of dictionaries
for dict in categoryarray as! NSDictionary {
        //extract the items from the dictionary. and concatenate names
        name = name + " " + dict["name"];
}
print("Name: ", name)
```

You can then use that information to populate your table cells as you wish. Obviously you will want to modify how the names are concatenated to suit your needs.

Hope that helps.